# Does lift decrease in hypersonic speed?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-mechanics, flight-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, aerospace

In John Bertin's Aerodynamics book, it is said that when the thickness of the boundary layer is low, the displacement thickness of the boundary layer is also low, and therefore the curvature of the streamlines due to the displacement thickness is small, and therefore the pressure gradient inside the boundary layer (y-axis) is ignored And pressure gradient in X direction are investigated ( in streamwise direction )
And he said that this assumption is not applicable at hypersonic speeds, that the pressure changes on the surface (pressure changes inside the boundary layer) are more than the pressure changes of the non-viscous layer outside the boundary layer.
Considering the high pressure on the surface at hypersonic speed, does the lift obtained from the pressure difference decrease?